# Issue running Cypress tests in the command line

Tags: node.js, angular, cypress

I am attempting to use start-server-and-test module to run cypress tests in the command line. Whenever I run it, it properly starts up the angular server and then runs through all of my tests. When it finishes the tests it errors out with the nondescript error message below. Any idea what could be causing this? I can run each step individually without start-server-and-test and they all work fine with no issues.

Package.json relevant lines

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
  "cypress:run": "cypress run",
  "start-chrome": "start-server-and-test start http://localhost:4200 cypress:run"
}
```

Error message:

```
Error: Command failed with exit code 32: npm run cypress:run
    at makeError (C:\Users\User\source\repos\syntelic-angular-ui\SynUI\syntelic-ui\node_modules\execa\lib\error.js:60:11)
    at handlePromise (C:\Users\User\source\repos\syntelic-angular-ui\SynUI\syntelic-ui\node_modules\execa\index.js:118:26)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  shortMessage: 'Command failed with exit code 32: npm run cypress:run',
  command: 'npm run cypress:run',
  escapedCommand: '"npm run cypress:run"',
  exitCode: 32,
  signal: undefined,
  signalDescription: undefined,
  stdout: undefined,
  stderr: undefined,
  failed: true,
  timedOut: false,
  isCanceled: false,
  killed: false
}
```

Comment: Do you get same if manually starting the server?

Comment: @Yolandi If I start the server manually with npm start and then run cypress:run it runs through the tests and exits normally at the end.